# PHP - List messages for each day

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I created a chat application in `PHP` and `jQuery`. The messages are stored into a database with a `UNIX timestamp` as post date.

Now I want to list each message sorted by day, but as you can see in the image it insert the day-divider twice while both messages are posted on the same day (Tuesday December 15, 2015). So this is wrong.

Does somebody knows how to fix this?

```
$messages = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Get the very first post-date in a UNIX timestamp
$previousDate = $messages['postTime'];

mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

$data = '';

while ($aMessages = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($previousDate <= $aMessages['postTime'])
    {
        // Create a new day-divider when a new day is reached.
        $data .= '<span>' . date("l F d, Y", $aMessages['postTime']) . '</span>';
    }

    $data .= $aMessages['message_text'];

    $previousDate = $aMessages['postTime'];
}
```

Comment: Can you post in your question your messages select php and mysql part ? so we will have from what to start our help

Comment: [*Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the first post to include some code. I removed unrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator must be minor instead minor or equal:

```
if ($previousDate < $aMessages['postTime'])
```

**EDIT**

A `Unix timestamp` is expressed in seconds, two dates in the same day may have different number of seconds. Try this:

```
if (date('Y-m-d', $previousDate) < date('Y-m-d', $aMessages['postTime']) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but got the same result as before.

Comment: The result is ordered by postTime?

Comment: Oh! I think that I understand where is the error. I'll make some tests.

Comment: You are awesome, this seems to work perfectly, thank you!